# Cannot fetch messages from another user FirebaseDatabase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-authentication

This is a simple chat messaging app, using Firebase Realtime Database and the Authentication. I have successfully created the database, but I cannot fetch the message from one user to another. Because, when I send the message/click the send button, it creates different nodes, I think its a string node with quotation mark in the name. The node structure I created is user-messages --> fromId(current user uid) --> toUid(to whom the messages are sent).

To make more clear explanation, this is the screenshot of what happened.
[image: This is when I send message from the first user.][image: Send message from the second user.]

I think the problem is, it creates a different nodes with the "uid", which means string. So the database has two nodes, one with the "...", and the other the normal one. For some info, I use some library such as Picasso image load, groupie, and parcelize.

This is the source code for the ChatLogActivity

```
import...

class ChatLogActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

companion object {
    val TAG = "ChatLog"
}

val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()
var toUser: User? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_log)
    recyclerview_chat_log.adapter = adapter
    toUser = intent.getParcelableExtra(NewMessageActivity.USER_KEY)
    titleChatLog.text = toUser?.nama

    listenForMessages()
    arrowBack.setOnClickListener {
        finish()
    }

    send_button_chat_log.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempt to send message.....")
        performSendMessage()
    }
}

private fun listenForMessages() {
    val fromId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
    val toId = toUser?.uid
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/user-messages/$fromId/$toId")
    ref.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
        override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            val chatMessage = p0.getValue(ChatMessage::class.java)
            if (chatMessage != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, chatMessage.text)
                if (chatMessage.fromId == FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid) {
                    val currentUser = LatestMessageActivity.currentUser?: return
                    adapter.add(ChatFromItem(chatMessage.text, currentUser))
                } else {
                    adapter.add(ChatToItem(chatMessage.text, toUser!!))
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {

        }

        override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {

        }

        override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {

        }
    })
}

private fun performSendMessage() {
    val text = edittext_chat_log.text.toString()
    val fromId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
    val user = intent.getParcelableExtra<User>(NewMessageActivity.USER_KEY)
    val toId = user.uid
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/user-messages/$fromId/$toId").push()
    val toRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/user-messages/$toId/$fromId ").push()
    if (fromId == null) return

    val chatMessage = ChatMessage(ref.key!!, text, fromId, toId, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
    ref.setValue(chatMessage)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d(TAG, "Save our chat message: ${ref.key}")
            edittext_chat_log.text.clear()
            recyclerview_chat_log.scrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)
        }
    toRef.setValue(chatMessage)
}
}

class ChatFromItem(val text: String, val user: User) : Item<ViewHolder>() {
override fun getLayout(): Int {
    return R.layout.chat_from_row
}

override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val uri = user.profileImageUrl
    val targetImageView = viewHolder.itemView.imageViewFrom
    Picasso.get().load(uri).into(targetImageView)
    viewHolder.itemView.textViewFrom.text = text
}
}

class ChatToItem(val text: String, val user: User) : Item<ViewHolder>() {
override fun getLayout(): Int {
    return R.layout.chat_to_row
}

override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val uri = user.profileImageUrl
    val targetImageView = viewHolder.itemView.imageViewTo
    Picasso.get().load(uri).into(targetImageView)
    viewHolder.itemView.textViewTo.text = text
}
}
```

And this is the ChatMessage, class that store the messages.

```
class ChatMessage(val id:String, val text: String, val fromId: String, val toId: String, val timeStamp: Long) {
constructor(): this("", "", "", "", -1)
}
```

I'm very glad if anyone can help this problem. Thank you

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb) using Kotlin.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for the tutorial, maybe later I'll learn more how to use cloud firestore